# problematic dot in url

Tags: python, web, turbogears2

I got a url parameter which contains 3 dots named token. suppose it is 'boo.foo.joo'.
my controller's method which is supposed to handle request only takes the first two parts ('boo.foo'). however I can see the remaining part in my `request.response_ext`.
what is `response_ext`? is this behavior coming from my web framework or is it a universal convention?

```
from tg import request

def recover_password(self, token):
    print(token) # outputs > 'boo.foo'
    print(request.response_ext) # outputs > '.joo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a feature of your framework](http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/rtfd2.2.2/main/Config.html#request-extensions) :

> base_config.disable_request_extensions – by default this is false.
>   This means that TG will take the request, and strip anything off the
>   end of the last element in the URL that follows ”.”. It will then take
>   this information, and assign an appropriate mime-type and store the
>   data in the tg.request.response_type and tg.request.response_ext
>   variables. By enabling this flag, you disable this behavior, rendering
>   TG unable to determine the mime-type that the user is requesting
>   automatically.

In your case, you may want to it to true to disable this behavior.

Comment: I thought it might be a convention and Im missing something. 
thanks for the answer :)